# scraping data from interactive chart produced by chrome extension

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I went through answers provided by the similar question but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I want to scrape date and price plotted in an interactive graph generated by an extension in chrome. I managed to find out the points being plotted by inspecting the page, but the problem is the details(date and price) appears when the cursor is moved to the point. How can I scrape these details?

extension url is as below:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buyhatke/jaehkpjddfdgiiefcnhahapilbejohhj?hl=en

Here is the screenshot of the graph generated by extension:
[image]

For now I managed to install extension and click price graph. 
my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('load-
extension=C:\\Users\\SACHIN\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User 
Data\\Default\\Extensions\\jaehkpjddfdgiiefcnhahapilbejohhj\\3.4.141_0')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get("https://paytm.com/shop/p/samsung-j3-pro-16-gb-black-MOBSAMSUNG-J3-PSTPL5914255C1B4E1C?src=grid&tracker=curated%7C%7Cmobile%20phones%7CCategory%20Grid%7C%2Fg%2Fmobile-accessories%2Fmobiles%2Fsmart-phones%7C66781%7C1%7C")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"hk-killerDIV\"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]")
element.click()
```

I really don't get what to do to scrape date and price generated when the cursor is moved on point.